# Excel Solver: y-intercept being forced to precisely zero. Why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

I have a set of data that is known to behave linearly and the data points have non-constant errors associated with them. I want to create a weighted least squares (WLS) regression on the data set.

If I do a simple LINEST fit, I get `y=5.225x-487.9` with `R^2=0.94` (so, pretty decent).

I then "guess" my coefficients of 5.0 and -400 to start the WLS. The sum of squared residuals (SSR) is minimized using the Excel Solver Add-In and plotted along with the original data set and the LINEST line.

The fit is *terrible*. The slope is turning out to be 3.147 and the intercept is precisely 0, which I know is incorrect.

Can someone please help with why the Solver is behaving this way?

Comment: Please [edit] the post into an Question/Answer format.  Ask a question and then post the answer as an answer and not in the question.  Posts that do not follow the correct formatting tend to get downvoted and deleted.

Comment: Corrected - thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**Just fixed it as I was re-doing the Solver to find the new slope**

The problem was the "Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative" checkbox. I unchecked that (since the slope and y-intercept are both unconstrained) and it resulted in the correct LINEST values.

I figured I would keep the post to help anyone else with this problem.